# merge MSO tag [hot] into [hot-questions]

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms, synonym-request, hot-questions

Suggest to merge Meta Stack Overflow tag [hot](/questions/tagged/hot) (11 questions as of now) into [hot-questions](/questions/tagged/hot-questions) (47 questions as of now).

Tags look the same to me. As for tag names, *hot-questions* sounds much more informative than *hot*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no need for a merge.  It took me less time to replace the [hot](/questions/tagged/hot) tag on the eleven questions it was on with the with the [hot-questions](/questions/tagged/hot-questions) tag than it took me to write this post.

It's done now.

Comment: thanks! I'do upvote your answer but I am out of votes today :)

Comment: @gnat No biggie.  Not sure something like this should get upvotes, it's just doing the work that needs to be done.